# Removing parenthesized subexpression

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

I have a String and want to delete from it all substrings with the following properties:

```
1. They start with an arbitrary (non-zero) number of open parenthesis
2. Then follows an arbitrary set of word characters (`\w`)
3. Then follows the same number of closing parenthesis as there have been open parenthesis.
```

Pure regular expressions can not match open and closing parenthesis. My first attempt wsa to find a way to use backreferences dynamically. I know that this is not valid Ruby, but to give you an idea:

```
sttrep = str.gsub(/([(]+) \w+ [)]#{\1.size}/x, '')
```

Of course the \1.size is invalid; but is there a way using interpolation, where I could evaluate something based on a backreference?

Another possible would be to repeatedly use `gsub` in a loop and remove one level of parenthesis at a time:

```
tmpstr = str
loop do
  strrep = tmpstr.gsub(/[(] ([(]\w+[)]) [)]/x, "(\\1)")
  if tmpstr == strrep
    # We only have one level of parenthesis to consider
    sttrep = str.gsub(/[(]\w+[)]/x, '')
    break
  else
    tmpstr = strrep
  end
end
# strrep is now the resulting string
```

However, this seems to be an overly complicated solution. Any ideas (except of course writing my owen string parser which loops over each character and counts the parenthesis)?

**UPDATE**:

Example1:

```
str = "ab((((cd))))ef((gh))ij(kl)mn"
```

`strrep` should contain *abefijmn*.

Example2:

```
str = "((((abc));def;((ghi)))"
```

`strrep` should contain *(;def;)*.

Comment: Could you please provide a string and the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, to match strings you described, you need to use regex subroutines:

```
(\((?:\w+|\g<1>)?\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewbC2Q/1).

*Details*:

- `(\((?:\w+|\g<1>)?\))` - Group 1 (capturing is necessary for recursion purposes):

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:\w+|\g<1>)?` - an optional occurrence of one or more word chars or Group 1 pattern recursed
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

To make it a bit more efficient, consider using an atomic group rather than a non-capturing group:

```
(\((?>\w+|\g<1>)?\))
    ^^
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/nxjm9S):

```rb
puts [
    'ab((((cd))))ef((gh))ij(kl)mn',
    '((((abc));def;((ghi)))',
    '(((foo)) , bar)'
].map {|x| x.gsub(/(\((?:\w+|\g<1>)?\))/, '')}
```

Output:

```
abefijmn
((;def;)
( , bar)
```

Comment: After trying it out to several strings, I **see** that it works, but I don't really understand it. For instance, the `\g<1>` matches the first capturing group. We have only one capturing group, which is the one we are "in" at the time of the match, and I vaguely feel that the `\g` is doing the recursion, but which substring exactly is it matching? We have not even completed the complete capturing group at this point.

Comment: @user1934428 `\g<1>` is a [regex subroutine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html). It is basically the placeholder (=it refers to) Group 1 *pattern*, not the text it captured (unlike backreferences). So, the whole pattern expands like this: `(\((?>\w+|(?>\((?>\w+)?\)))?\))`, `(\((?>\w+|(\((?>\w+|(\((?>\w+)?\)))?\)))?\))`, etc. until the max recursion value or no match. Note the recursion levels are atomic.

Comment: I see. I now also found [this](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Grouping) explanation. This makes it clearer. It's a bit like in a recursive-descent parser, when I'm inside an expression and I want to match a sub-expression, isn't it? Thanks for enlightening me here.

Comment: @user1934428 This is just a recursion construct, usually used to match balanced constructs.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you don't need to parse anything "complex" like arbitrary S-expressions etc - all you're interested in is just to eliminate things like `(((foo)))` and `((bar))` (they have the same number of opening/closing parens) but keep things like `(((foo)) bar)` intact.

If this assumption is correct then quite simple `gsub` can do the job:

```
def delete_parentheses(str)
  str.gsub(/(\(+)\w+(\)+)/) do |match|
    $1.size == $2.size ? "" : match
  end
end

delete_parentheses("Here ((be)) dragons") # => Here dragons
delete_parentheses("Here ((be) dragons") # Here ((be) dragons
```

Comment: Good point! I did not think about the case `(((foo)) bar)`, because it can't occur in my input. It would have to be i.e. `(((foo)) , bar)`, and this should be transformed to `(, bar)`.

Comment: Wow, this changes things a lot I'd say :) Whitespaces and commas are not considered word characters, but this is less of a problem. The bigger one is that you DO have to parse S-expressions...

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. My bad that I didn't understand this complexity initially.

Comment: Reason is that `(((foo)) , bar)` **does have** as substring `((foo))`, and this - according to my definition, is something to be removed.

Comment: But I think I can build on the solution you gave. It's just a bit more complicated: If the sizes of $1 and $2 are different, I take the smaller of those sizes - and this is the number of parentheses to remove. With other words: I have to return `$1.size - $2.size` opening parenthesis, if I have more opening than closing parenthesis, and vice versa.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely relevant. With the changes I mentioned before, it seems to do what I wanted. If it's fine for you, I edit your answer to match it to my updated question.   The crucial point was that `gsub` can be invoked with a block. I was not aware about this feature.